# Url Encoding of dictionary with AFNetworking in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, afnetworking-2, url-encoding

i have to send `POST` request in following format to the server:

Content Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
`Form Key : data`
Form Value :

```
[
 {
   "email" : "test@test.com",
   "password" : "test@test.com"     
 }
]
```

When i send request by this format in web rest client (Postman/Advance Rest Client),i got success in response.

So how can i send this type of response with `AFNetworking`?

My code for `Objective-c` is

```
NSDictionary *dictLogin = @{@"email":@"test@test.com",@"password":@"test@test.com"};
NSDictionary *dictReq = @{@"data":@[dictLogin]};
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictReq options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *strReq = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:@"http://test.php" parameters:dictReq success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

When i pass **dictReq** or **str** as AFNetworking parameter i got response of missing parameter/failure response from server

If it's not possible or hard with `AFNetworking` , `NSUrlConnection/Request` will also work

Thanks

Comment: did you make sure that your keys are correct ones for the JSON, that they are the ones expected on the server side? Because the JSON example from the above is different from what you're generation by the code in Objective-c

Comment: Yes , Parameters are the same , what difference you find both req ? in rest client i have separate the data key and parameters  ,  my code i have written it as dictionary

Comment: Have you fixed this issue. Can you please share your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, I've used AFNetworking for many projects. And ever had to encode Parameters.

```
NSDictionary *dictLogin = @{@"email":@"test@test.com",@"password":@"test@test.com"};
NSDictionary *dictReq = @{@"data":@[dictLogin]};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];



[manager POST:@"http://test.php" parameters:dictReq success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Comment: Hi i'm using the same code , what difference does this make than my code ?

Comment: You're trying to serialize the data yourself, apart from AFNetworking, instead of letting AFNetworking serialize it.  Don't serialize it and convert it to NSData.